# Clone method usage in Java

Tags: java, arrays, clone

What is the use of `clone()` here?

```
String[] arg0 = (String[]) this.command.toArray(new String[this.command.size()]);   // List<String> command;
arg0 = (String[]) arg0.clone();   //Line#2
String[] arg1 = arg0;
```

I am not getting what is line#2 trying to achieve after all?

I checked how `clone()` is defined

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

but couldn't make much sense out of it. I am relatively new to Java.

Comment: It really has no point here. You are cloning the contents and assigning to the same variable again.

Comment: Where did you see this code? This doesn't seem like good practice to me.

Comment: In my company code base.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao that's exactly what came to my mind.

Comment: Does the code break if you remove it?

Comment: There is no point of having `clone` anywhere: it is generally not a reliable way of achieving what it says on the tin, making clones of objects.

Answer (score 0):

It makes a copy of the array so that future changes to the array do not have influence to the original array.

It is hard to say if the clone makes sense in this example. One would need to see the details of the `this.command.toArray` method.

Comment: If command is a `List<String>` the clone does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You convert the List to an Array and then you clone the Array. Any updates to the cloned new Array don't affect your original Array. If you now update the cloned Array you are not affecting the original array. 
Depending on your ToArray method if the list returns the original Array in which the list is stored any update to the Array could have updated the list but in this case as you have cloned it the updates to the clone cannot affect the List.